# Is it possible to stringify an array object with function saved in it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, function, serialization, deserialization

I have a code that generates how many users I wanted to create in an array.

```
let x;

const collection = {
  count: 2,
  array: [],
  create: function(ind) {
    this.array.push({
      name: "user " + ind,
      alert: function() {
        alert(this.name);
      }
    });
  }
};

for(let i = 0; i < collection.count; i++) {
    collection.create(i);
};
```

When I tried to convert it to string,

```
x = JSON.stringify(collection.array);
console.log(x);
```

It just shows this. It doesn't save the function inside the object. Which means, I can't call the user to broadcast the user name itself.

```
'[{"name":"user0"},{"name":"user1"}]'
```

Is it even possible to convert this array with functions in it to string with just JavaScript? Or just download the file having the function of each user?

Comment: JSON is for data, not functions. What are you planning to do with this JSON? Why are you trying to put functions in JSON?

Comment: Exactly like the name "stringify" you're converting an Object's data into a String.

Comment: For me your code is working fine. I don't see any issue in that.

Comment: It shouldn't be that difficult to consult some documentation first ... E.g. at MDN already the second paragraph states ... [_"JSON is a syntax for serializing **objects**, **arrays**, **numbers**, **strings**, **booleans**, and **null**. It is based upon JavaScript syntax but is distinct from it: some JavaScript is not JSON."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Comment: Instead of transporting redundant functional overhead like suggested by an answer via e.g. `'[{ "name": "user 1", "alertStr": "function() { console.log(this.name); }" }]'` per object, the receiving side should parse the plain object data and add the functional part right after via e.g `map` ... `function logName () { console.log(this.name); } const itemList = JSON.parse(data).map(item => ({ ...item, logName }));`

Comment: I was doing a game where the level editor requires to save the data of each entities to string so I can copy it as a text, paste it in a text area, assign it then load their value. But the functions aren't written in it, this means I can't call their functions.

Comment: @Demobnector ... But one could recreate the entities from the serialized data. The only thing needed is the state, the pure data itself. The behavior, thus the methods can be added with the recreation process. But as for the answers which target your serialization question, did you already have a look into the code which shows the possible usage of  _`JSON.stringify` replacers_ and _`JSON.parse` reviviers_?

Comment: @Demobnector ... Regarding the so far two answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account two comments of mine ...

> Instead of transporting redundant functional overhead like suggested by an answer via e.g.
>
> ```
> '[{ "name": "user 1", "alertStr": "function() { console.log(this.name); }" }]'
> ```
>
> per object, the receiving side should parse the plain object data and add the functional part right after via e.g map ...
>
> ```
> function logName () {
>   console.log(this.name);
> }
> const itemList = JSON
>   .parse(data)
>   .map(item => ({ ...item, logName }));
> ```

> And how about deserializing via `JSON.parse` then? The result is an array with two objects where each object features an `alertStr` property with the redundant string value of `'function() { console.log(this.name); }'`. How does this help the OP without having to use an `eval` based approach (either directly via `eval` or by parsing and `new Function( ... )`)? In addition, I consider `Function.prototype.toString` not a reliable method for the suggested purpose of saving a function's implementation.

.., I want to draw the OP's attention to the [`replacer` parameter/function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) of `JSON.stringify` and the [`reviver` parameter/function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) of `JSON.parse`.

The next provided example code has a more educational purpose, and any production code should try to avoid this solution by navigating around and/or solving the OP's real problem.

```js
// +++ slightly improved OP example code +++

function logName() {
  console.log(this.name);
}
const collection = {
  count: 2,
  array: [],
  create: function(idx) {
    this.array.push({
      name: `user ${ idx }`,
      logName,
    });
  },
};

for (let i = 0; i < collection.count; i++) {
  collection.create(i);
};
console.log({
  collectionArray: collection.array,
});
collection.array[0].logName();
collection.array[1].logName();

console.log({
  plainlyStringified: JSON.stringify(collection.array),
});


// +++ serializing with a map/index based approach for function implementations +++

const functionImplementationIndex = {
  logName: ['console.log(this.name);'],
  //total: ['a', 'b', 'return a + b;'],
}

function serializeFunction(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    value = {
      isFunction: true,
      newFuncArgs: functionImplementationIndex[key] ?? [],
    };
  }
  return value;
}
const serializedArrayData =
  JSON.stringify(collection.array, serializeFunction);

console.log({ serializedArrayData });


// +++ deserializing/parsing again +++

function deserializeFunction(key, value) {
  if (
    value.hasOwnProperty('isFunction')
    && (value.isFunction === true)
  ) {
    value = new Function(...(value.newFuncArgs ?? []));
  }
  return value;
}
const deserializedArray =
  JSON.parse(serializedArrayData, deserializeFunction);

console.log({ deserializedArray });
console.log({
  collectionArray: collection.array,
});
deserializedArray[0].logName();
deserializedArray[1].logName();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really. But you can do a some trick.
You can stringify function with `.toString()` method

For example

```
fn = () => 'hello world';
fn.toString();  // "() => 'hello world'"
```

So you can add this "hack" to array:

```js
const collection = {
  count: 2,
  array: [],
  create: function(ind) {
    const name = "user " + ind;
    const alert = function() { console.log(this.name); };
    const alertStr = alert.toString();
    this.array.push({ name, alert, alertStr });
  }
};

collection.create(1);
collection.create(2);

collection.array[0].alert()
collection.array[1].alert()

console.log(JSON.stringify(collection.array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: And how about deserializing via `JSON.parse` then? the result is an array with two objects where each object features an `alertStr` property with the redundant string value of `'function() { console.log(this.name); }'`. How does this help the OP without having to use an `eval` based approach (either directly via `eval` or by parsing and `new Function( ... )`)? In addition, I consider `Function.prototype.toString` not a reliable method for the suggested purpose of saving a function's implementation.

Comment: @PeterSeliger OP don't ask about deserializing.

Comment: Serializing does imply deserializing at a certain point; thus the serializing part should already take it into account by coming up with a reasonable serializing approach.